# How to develop golang modules efficiently

Tags: go

I'm developing a golang project and a shared module simultaneously.
I feel the process is annoying If shared module is modified.

steps:

1. write something in shared module and give it a new GIT tag.
2. get latest module version in my project
3. test, if any bug is found, back to step (1)

Can anyone give a more efficient way?

Comment: Maybe [Can I work entirely outside of VCS on my local filesystem](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem)? [How to develop and test a local go module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648427/how-to-develop-and-test-a-local-go-module)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328952/how-to-use-a-module-that-is-outside-of-gopath-in-another-module/52330233#52330233??

Comment: That's what the `replace` directive in go.mod is for. Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're developing, I'd recommend just using `replace` directives in your `go.mod` to make any changes in dependencies instantly visible (regardless of version) to client code.

E.g. if you have package "client" using package "auth":

`$SOMEDIR/client/go.mod` would `replace` dependency on client with `$SOMEDIR/auth`, and now you can just develop the two alongside each other in `$SOMEDIR`, commit changes to source control, etc.

When you're ready to "ship" it, you'll have to create an actual version for these modules. That is, if you even want `auth` to be separately usable from `client`. Consider keeping everything as private as possible (using `internal`).

---

Read this [official documentation on the subject](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/call-module-code) for more details